# Best way to do a remote directory compare with Powershell

Tags: powershell, deployment, scripting

I have 2 folders:

```
$srcPath = \\stagingserver
$destPath = \\productionserver
```

I'd like to compare the two to determine what changes are in the $src folder than haven't been pushed to production yet. The project is ~4000 files over 100 directories totalling ~80mb. I'm currently doing a hash compare like so:

```
$src = Get-ChildItem $srcPath -Recurse
$dest = Get-ChildItem $destPath -Recurse 
$same = Compare-Object $src $dest -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime -passthru -includeequal -excludeDifferent

$srcTree = Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse -exclude $same | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash
$destTree = Get-ChildItem $dest -Recurse -exclude $same | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash  

$diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $srcTree -differenceObject $destTree | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } | % {$_.InputObject.Path}
```

It takes ~5 minutes to do. I take it because it needs to copy everything locally to perform the hash. How can I do this quicker? Is there a way to maintain a hash value for every file on the server? Should I execute scripts remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing files, you could use `robocopy` to synchronize the staging share contents into the production share. `/MIR` flag can be used to mirror, that is, remove non-existing files from the destination. Robocopy uses timestamps to determine if file needs to be copied, so there are some caveats.

If hashes are needed, you could create a script on remote server that stores file hashes in a CSV file. Afterwards, it should be easy enough to import the CSV file and compare local hashes to the file contents.